# Breaking down a function into more manageable segments

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a program right now that I'm trying to break down into smaller, more manageable pieces for exercise purposes. The problem is though, I'm experiencing a bit of difficulty in following the guidelines set. This notably being that a function *cannot* contain more than 6 statements.

Here is how the program originally looked..

```
def print_monthly_totals (input_csv_filename):
'''Read the given CSV file and print the totals for each month.
   The input file is assumed to have the month number in column 1,
   the number of days in the month in column 2 and the floating
   point rainfalls (in mm) for each month in the remaining columns
   of the row. 
'''
    data = open(input_csv_filename).readlines()
    print('Rainfall totals for each month')
    for line in data:
        columns = line.split(',')
        month = int(columns[0])
        num_days = int(columns[1])
        total_rainfall = 0
        for col in columns[2 : 2 + num_days]:
        total_rainfall += float(col)
        print('Month {:2}: {:.1f}'.format(month, total_rainfall))

print_monthly_totals('rainfalls2011.csv')
```

I managed to break this down into two separate functions giving me ..

```
def print_monthly_totals(input_csv_filename):
    data = open(input_csv_filename).readlines()
    print('Rainfall totals for each month')
    for line in data:
        columns = line.split(',')
        month = int(columns[0])
        num_days = int(columns[1])     
        trf = rainfall_total(columns, num_days)  
        print('Month {:2}: {:.1f}'.format(month, trf))  

def rainfall_total(columns, num_days):
    total_rainfall = 0
    for col in columns[2 : 2 + num_days]:
        total_rainfall += float(col)      
    return total_rainfall

print_monthly_totals('rainfalls2011.csv')
```

But my `print_monthly_totals` function is *still* too big and I need to create a third function to satisfy the 6 statements per function rule. The attempt I had just results in a flurry of global name is not defined errors..

```
def print_monthly_totals(input_csv_filename):
    data = open(input_csv_filename).readlines()      
    print('Rainfall totals for each month')
    trf = rainfall_total(columns, num_days)        
    print('Month {:2}: {:.1f}'.format(month, trf))      

def data():
    for line in data:
        columns = line.split(',')
        month = int(columns[0])
        num_days = int(columns[1])         

def rainfall_total(columns, num_days):
    '''Guts of the program'''
    total_rainfall = 0
    for col in columns[2 : 2 + num_days]:
        total_rainfall += float(col)      
    return total_rainfall

print_monthly_totals('rainfalls2011.csv')
```

Any help would be appreciated, cheers!

Comment: Maybe a good fit for codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: BTW `.split(',')` isn't good for CSV in general because some may look like `123,456,"a,b,c",789` (4 columns). Use the [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
def print_monthly_totals(input_csv_filename):
    with open(input_csv_filename) as csv_file:
        data = csv_file.readlines()
        print('Rainfall totals for each month')
        for line in data:
            manage_line(line)


def manage_line(line):
        columns = line.split(',')
        month = int(columns[0])
        num_days = int(columns[1])     
        trf = rainfall_total(columns, num_days)  
        print('Month {:2}: {:.1f}'.format(month, trf))  

def rainfall_total(columns, num_days):
    total_rainfall = 0
    for col in columns[2 : 2 + num_days]:
        total_rainfall += float(col)      
    return total_rainfall

print_monthly_totals('rainfalls2011.csv')
```

This sounds pretty close to what you may want.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Nice; two issues: 1. `print_monthly_totals` could use a `with open(...) as ...`, 2. `rainfall_total` can be simplified into `return sum(...)`

Answer (score 1):

```
def parse_line(data):
    columns = data.split(',')
    month = int(columns[0])
    num_days = int(columns[1])
    return month, num_days

def rainfall_total(columns, num_days):
    total_rainfall = 0
    for col in columns[2 : 2 + num_days]:
        total_rainfall += float(col)      
    return total_rainfall

def print_monthly_totals(input_csv_filename):
    with open(input_csv_filename) as fh:
        for line in fh:
            month, days = parse_line(line)
            print('Rainfall totals for each month')
            trf = rainfall_total(columns, num_days)        
            print('Month {:2}: {:.1f}'.format(month, trf))      

print_monthly_totals('rainfalls2011.csv')
```

Something along those lines perhaps.
Obviously this might not work.. is a bit messy but i'll continue to edit it and hopefully you get the idea.

Benefits:

- No filehandles left open
- Functions in called order
- removed excessive code

Comment: I guess the last method has at least 9 statements

Answer (score 0):

This take also shows how to use the `csv` module:

```
def print_monthly_totals (input_csv_filename):
    '''
    Read the given CSV file and print the totals for each month.
    The input file is assumed to have the month number in column 1,
    the number of days in the month in column 2 and the floating
    point rainfalls (in mm) for each month in the remaining columns
    of the row. 
    '''    
    import csv
    print('Rainfall totals for each month')
    with open(input_csv_filename) as csv_file:
        for row in csv.reader(csv_file):
            print_row(row)

def print_row(columns):
    month = int(columns[0])
    num_days = int(columns[1])
    total_rainfall = sum(float(val) for val in columns[2:2+num_days])
    print('Month {:2}: {:.1f}'.format(month, total_rainfall))

print_monthly_totals('rainfalls2011.csv')
```